# Vertices, their labels, and how to refer to them?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In the examples I have seen, graph vertices in Mathematica are usually explicit small integers. However, Wolfram documentation says that vertices can be any arbitrary expression (eg., george, x^2, London, 5).

Nevertheless, it seems that vertices are always *referred to* by number, that is, by the position of the vertex expression in `VertexList[gr]`. This can be confusing. For example, if I build a graph like this, using nonconsecutive vertex numbers,

```
Graph[1<->2, 2<->10, 10<->3, 3<->4]
```

then I still have to refer to the vertices as if I had made each vertex number equal to its creation order, as if I had built the graph with strictly consecutive vertex numbers:

```
Graph[1<->2, 2<-3 ,3<->4, 4<->1]
```

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can refer to the vertices in any order and it will pair it accordingly. Compare the following:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 10, 10 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
g2 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 10, 10 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, 
    VertexLabels -> {1 -> "a", 10 -> "b", 2 -> "c", 4 -> "d", 3 -> "e"}]
```

[image]

Note that in the second case, I named the vertices in a different order than what was entered and did not use sequential numbers.

Comment: But if I write:
 `code`g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 10, 10 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"];
GraphPlot[g1,VertexLabeling->True]
then the result uses only the digits 1 through 8. That is, at the very least, confusing, don't you think?